# Getting the height of an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this image : `<img style="border-bottom-right-radius:0px;" id="cover_image" src="Daft+Punk+Tron+Legacy.jpg" alt="cover" width="851"  />` , I have set the width of the image and the photo automatically keeps aspect ratio and resize both width to 851 and height to a certain value, I want to grab the height value with Javascript but it's not working

So far I have tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($("#cover_image").height());
});
```

When I try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        alert($("#cover_image").width());
    });
```

it works and it shows 851 which is the correct value of the width, but when I use height is returns 0.. can you point me in the right direction please ?

Comment: please refer below URL

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Comment: @Mac It's `height()`, not `height`, which is meant to be the computed value: http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: i didn't get your point. what you finally want to do ?

Comment: I have that image and by setting the width a value, it automatically resizes to that width and an unknown height keeping the aspect ratio of the image, I want to grab that height with javascript, that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use onload event of the image:

```
$("#cover_image").on('load',function(){
    if(this.complete) alert($(this).height());
});
```

Comment: you are the master of javascript, thank you so much it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

clientWidth and clientHeight are DOM properties that show the current in-browser size of the inner dimensions of a DOM element (excluding margin and border). So in the case of an IMG element, this will get the actual dimensions of the visible image.

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
//or however you get a handle to the IMG
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

Thanks
AB